# How to specify makeargs in configure script?

Tags: linux, gnu-make

while building how to give include paths and library paths in **configure** script with --makeargs= ? I mean what is the syntax for makeargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set these flags either in the environment or on the `./configure` command line. There are three variables to set:

- `CPPFLAGS` is flags for the C preprocessor. Include flags (`-I`) go here, as do `-D` definitions.
- `CFLAGS` are flags for the C compiler. Optimisation flags and machine-specific flags go here.
- `LDFLAGS` are for the linker. `-L` flags go here.

You can set them in the evironment:

```
$ export CPPFLAGS='-I/foo/bar/baz/include'
$ export LDFLAGS='-L/foo/bar/baz/lib'
$ ./configure
```

Or you can set them on the command line:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS='-I/foo/bar/baz/include' LDFLAGS='-L/foo/bar/baz/lib'
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally it's safer to use two macros instead of one.  One for include directives and one for linking directives:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(cflags,
[  --with-cflags=CFLAGS            use CFLAGS as compile time arguments.],
    [CFLAGS=$with_cflags; export CFLAGS])

AC_ARG_WITH(ldflags,
[  --with-ldflags=LDFLAGS          use LDFLAGS as link time arguments to ld.],
    [LDFLAGS=$with_ldflags; export LDFLAGS])
```

Then ./configure --with-cflags="-I/path/one -I/path/two" --with-ldflags="-L/path/other" work.

Comment: No. If you're using an autotooled package, it responds to the `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` env vars anyway. You can set them either in your environment or as `./configure CFLAGS='-ffoo -mbar' CPPFLAGS='-I/path/one -I/path/two` LDFLAGS='-L/path/lib'`.

Comment: I find most people prefer --help output that lists specific options rather than passing in the above environment vars.  I actually do know they're supported, but I don't think it's as pleasant from a usability point of view.  Now, having said that, I don't think the whole configure process itself is all that wonderful usability anyway.

Comment: If you run `./configure --help`, you will see that it also lists the influential environment variables in its output. Also, is it really worth making your package different to the rest of the world? The whole point of the GBS is to create a uniform experience for the user.